# How to convert Hexadecial IP address into dotted notation in c/c++

Tags: c, ip, hex, ip-address

Following the Hex representation of Ip address:

IP address in hex format:

```
ffffffc0
```

How to convert this into dotted notation?

Comment: Does `ffffffc0` means either `0xffffffc0` or `"ffffffc0"`?

Comment: It is just "ffffffc0" and it is not in the string format as given in the example you think of its duplicate. It is just in hex format.

Comment: [example](http://ideone.com/ZscecN)